# How to play flv video on mobile web browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

Is it possible to view .flv format video movies with standard android web browsers fromm my web page? I tried to watch using videojs, but get an error "no compatible source was found for this video".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Mobile browsers do not support flv. On desktop, video.js and other players use Flash to play flv. Flash is not available on mobile devices.